# window state maximize not working

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I am opening a form in a mdi parent.  I show the form in the parent and the window state of the new form in the designer is maximized.  For some reason, the form appears in the top left corner of the mdi parent, and the control box is way over to the right as if it was maximized, but the size of the window is not filling up the screen.  So the behavior is as if it were maximized, but it is not filling the screen.  What should I do?

I'm using C#.Net Winform.

Answer (score 1):

Set your child form's window state to maximized. 
This will maximize your form.

```
childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

You can do this on load of your MdiParent form, or whenever you open show this child form.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your MdiChilds [`MaximumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize.aspx) Property is not set. If it is it will look like this, which looks like what you have described in your question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Coming in late, but I too am having this problem and so far nobody's answered why it's happening.  I found this [discussion on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/01c1726b-ae74-462c-b958-6da236a5d632/form-wont-display-as-maximized-even-though-windowstate-is-set-to-maximized?forum=winforms) that explains more of what is really a workaround suggested by @nunespascal:

Basically I can't set WindowState to Maximised in the Designer, but if I leave it set to Normal and then when loading the form in code I set it to Maximised it works.

This is also the answer provided in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28357658/1736266).