# Maximized state of child form Not working correctly when used in MDI container (Visual Basic 2013)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I am having this weird problem in Visual Basic (2013). I have a form in MDI container. Both of them, have property `WindowState` to `Maximized`. While executing, MDI container loads in maximized state (So far Ok!). But, when I **open the child form, it Does NOT give the Actual Maximized state appearance** (although Restore button on top right shows that it has loaded in maximized state, but it did not maximized).

I even tried with `form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` both before and after `form1.Show()`, but no luck.

I have attached a screenshot too. Note the dead space of MDI container and Restore icon of child form (which means child form is in maximized state).

[image: screenshot of VB problem]

Few observations -

1. When I restore and then again maximize it, it DOES maximize correctly.
2. I also observed that this problem is occurs only for one time. I mean, if I have 2 forms both set to load in Maximized state. When I open the first form (no matter which), it loads like i showed in the screenshot, and after that when I open 2nd form, it loads in maximized state.

I could not figure out, what went wrong? How to correct this?

Comment: Show us code that duplicates the problem.  Don't create MDI Child forms in the parent's constructor.

Answer (score 7):

go to your form properties. Set windowsState = normal. then put this to code

```
    Dim frmC As New frmChild
    frmC.MdiParent = Me
    frmC.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    frmC.Show()
```

Comment: this solution worked for our bug, where a Windows.Form with property "WindowsState" set to Maximized was redrawn not correctly inside an MDIContainer form.

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting the MDI child form to maximized within the New routine of the class works always OK.

```
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

OK, the last line may be one you may code under a condition...

Answer (score 0):

Check your icon. It must contain a 16x16 page. If the smallest is 32x32, the problem you illustrate will arise.